# accessing the phone number of a text message in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I m new in android, i m trying to get the number of a text message when a new message comes, i m using broadcast reciever for this. but when a new message comes my 'broadcast reciever' class not working. can anyone help me to find out the problem. giving my code below..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
    }


     public class MyBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String smsnumber = "";         
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the sender number SMS received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                smsnumber =  msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();         
            }
        } 
    }
}

}
```

i had given the recieve tag in manifest.

```
 <receiver android:name="com.aucupa.iack.MyBroadcastReciever" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

given the uses permission for recieving sms too..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

but when an sms comes no response from the MyBroadcastReciever class.when i debug the control not comes to the MyBroadcastReciever class. plz help me to find out the problem

finally i got the answer from all your help, giving my answer here..

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

  MyBroadcastReciever broadcastreciever = new MyBroadcastReciever();
  static final String SOME_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
  IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SOME_ACTION);

  Intent i = new Intent(SOME_ACTION);
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

sendBroadcast(i);
context.registerReceiver(broadcastreciever, intentFilter);
}


 public class MyBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
   if (intent.getAction() == "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"){
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String smsnumber = "";         
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the sender number SMS received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            smsnumber =  msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();         
        }
    } 
 }
}
}

}
```

Comment: What is the error actually you received?

Comment: have you declare your receiver in manifest ?

Comment: @ling.s plz check my error log. i had given all the permission in manifest

Comment: Please do not take a screenshot of logcat, instead copy the text and post/format that.

Comment: post your manifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In manifest
use this Premission

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

and

```
     <receiver android:name="net.app.sms.MessageReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

try this...

**EDITED**

```
     <receiver android:name="Your PackageName.ClassName" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: whr should i provide reciever part in manifest? inside application tag? anything else should i do like registering broadcast reciever like that?

Comment: inside a application tag       <receiver android:name="Your Class Name With package" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

Comment: i mgetting error like class not found exception in net.app.sms.MessageReceiver.

Comment: hello in receiver tag Give your Class name Not mine"net.app.sms.MessageReceiver is my class name...

Comment: U didn't have a MessageReceiver Class You have MyBroadcastReciever class pls mention ur class name in manifest

Comment: ' <receiver android:name="YourPackage.YourClassName" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>'

Answer (score 2):

in your MyBroadcastReciever which extends BroadcastReceiver, inside onReceive() try this code

```
 if (intent.getAction() == android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                       // your rest of code

                }
            }
```

Comment: its getting this error android.provider.Telephony cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: intent.getAction() == "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"

Comment: try above put it in double quotes

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with registering/unregistering the `BroadcastReceiver` and also removed manifest declaration.

Define `ReceiveMessages` as an inner class within the `Activity` which needs to listen for messages from the `Service`.

Then, declare class variables such as...

```
 ReceiveMessages myReceiver = null;
 Boolean myReceiverIsRegistered = false;
```

In `onCreate()` use `myReceiver = new ReceiveMessages();`

Then in `onResume()`...

```
if (!myReceiverIsRegistered) {
    registerReceiver(myRecever, new IntentFilter("com.mycompany.myapp.SOME_MESSAGE"));
    myReceiverIsRegistered = true;
}
```

...and in `onPause()`...

```
if (myReceiverIsRegistered) {
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    myReceiverIsRegistered = false;
}
```

In the `Service` create and broadcast the `Intent`...

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.mycompany.myapp.SOME_MESSAGE");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

And that's about it. Make the 'action' unique to your package / app, i.e., `com.mycompany...` as in my example. This helps avoiding a situation where other apps or system components might attempt to process it.

Answer (score 0):

To receive intents for your defined BroadcastReceiver, you either delcare the receiver in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<receiver android:name="full qualified name of your receiver">
    <action android:name="the action interests you"/>
</receiver>
```

or register it with Context.registerReceiver:

```
Context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

Otherwise, system cannot know your receiver exists. For some special sensitive intents(like SMS) you also need to delcare permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: how to register with Context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter); what should i provide the parameters, can u fill it with my example..

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and rebuilding your code. Some times we need to do cleaning on making updates to the code.

You have to register two way.

**static and dynamic**

more information you can see this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).

**OR**

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    Cursor cur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null,null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
       id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("thread_id"));        
       protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
       Long date=cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("date"));
       type = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("type"));
       String address=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));

       System.out.println("READING LOG...."+"\n thread_id:"+id+"\n protocol:"+protocol+"\n type:"+type+"\n address"+address);
           if(protocol==null && (type==2 || type==4 || type==6)){
             Log.i("======TEST====", "MESSAGE SENT.......number:"+address);
           }else if(protocol!=null && type==1){               
                Log.i("======TEST====", "MESSAGE RECEIVE.......number:"+address);
           }else{
            //something message
           }
```

try this one.